# How to check ruby-2.6.3 is using jemalloc ? I installed ruby-2.6.3 as $ rvm install 2.6.3 -C --with-jemalloc

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jemalloc

This command should show -ljemalloc but it is not. I could see it with ruby-2.4.3 and ruby-2.5.x but not with ruby-2.6.x

```
$ ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS']"
-lm                                                                                                                                    
$ cat /etc/environment


PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.1
```

I am using ubuntu 18 LTS and with other ruby version , I am getting the jemalloc file library as mention above

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In ruby `2.6.x`, you have to check `MAINLIBS`, like this:

```
$ irb -rrbconfig
irb(main):004:0> RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS']
=> "-lz -lpthread -lrt -lrt -ljemalloc -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm "
```

or, of course, with your one-liner:

```
$ ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS']"
-lz -lpthread -lrt -lrt -ljemalloc -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Comment: to install jemalloc , used the command   1-sudo apt-get install libjemalloc-dev

Comment: to install jemalloc , used the command  
 1-sudo apt-get install libjemalloc-dev

to reinstall ruby with rvm I used the following command  

RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-jemalloc rvm reinstall 2.6.3

but still jemalloc library ,I am not getting with the suggested command.

Comment: I don't know, but it should be quite easy to install Ruby with jemalloc using `rvm`, it goes simply like this: `rvm install 2.6.3 -C --with-jemalloc` (or `rvm reinstall 2.6.3 -C --with-jemalloc` if you're reinstalling it).

Comment: I used your command and now I am able to see the jemalloc library . Many thanks!!