# Suffixed RVM Ruby version mentionned in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler, gemfile

Until now I was specifying the version of Ruby used in my gemfile this way :

gemfile :

```
ruby '2.6.6'
```

This version of Ruby is installed with RVM.

Now I have compiled this version of Ruby with Jemalloc and suffixed it. So `rvm list` returns the following :

```
=> ruby-2.6.6 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.6-jemalloc [ x86_64 ]
```

Yet I don't know how to specify the jemalloc version of Ruby in the Gemfile. Is there a specific syntax to use ?

Answer (score 0):

there are many builtin constant in ruby

```sh
$ ruby -e 'puts Module.constants' | grep RUBY_
RUBY_VERSION
RUBY_PLATFORM
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE
RUBY_REVISION
RUBY_ENGINE
RUBY_PATCHLEVEL
RUBY_ENGINE_VERSION
RUBY_COPYRIGHT
RUBY_DESCRIPTION
```

you are interested in `RUBY_PATCHLEVEL`

```sh
$ ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION, RUBY_PATCHLEVEL'
2.7.1
83
```

Comment: Hi @Mr. Thanks for your answer though I have displayed every constants for both version and they are strictly identical. "2.6.6 146  etc .."

Comment: @Maxence: then you probably did not compile the ruby engine as you should if these variables are all the same for you

Comment: I used this technique : https://scalingo.com/blog/improve-ruby-application-memory-jemalloc and when checking it seems to work: following this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303214/how-to-check-ruby-2-6-3-is-using-jemalloc-i-installed-ruby-2-6-3-as-rvm-inst I get proper flag on jemalloc version. Does compiling the Engine make something different apart from allowing to distinguish versions ?